# javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: No validator could be found for type java.time.LocalDateTime. See: @Past at private java.time.LocalDateTime

Tags: java, java-8, hibernate-validator, websphere-9

I am maintaining an old application that is built on Java 8 and deployed in a WebSphere 9.

I've added `javax.validation.constraints.Past` annotation in a `java.time.LocalDateTime` field, like this:

```
@Past
private LocalDateTime dataMandato;
```

My dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.15.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.15.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

But when I deploy the code and execute it I get:

```
javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: No validator could be found for type java.time.LocalDateTime. See: @Past at private java.time.LocalDateTime br.com.company.project.dto.pessoa.EntradaCadastroPessoaFisicaDTO.dataMandato
```

And in my WebSphere shared libs I have the following:

[image: WebSphere shared libs]

Am I missing any other dependency?